# new ArrayList<Class>() or new ArrayList<>() in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Lets assume that I have a variable:

```
List<String> myList;
```

Is there a difference between these two lines?

```
myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I guess both does the same on compilation, but still I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called Type inference for Generics and was added in Java 7.

Both versions of the code you wrote are the same.

There are a few caveats you might want to read about here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Comment: Please make an effort to find a duplicate before attempting an answer. I'm sure you've seen this question before.

Comment: Diamond operator.. I didn't know that it counts as an operator! Thanks for the link (Y)

Comment: I searched for that @SotiriosDelimanolis . I couldn't find any result, because I didn't even know <> counted as an operator.

Comment: It's not really an operator, it just ended up getting called that.